# Get JSON Object Value when it's called "class" PHP keyword?

Tags: php, json

This is something I actually haven't come across before. I'm calling which is using the word `class` in it.

I'm trying to get the JSON object value in PHP like so:

```
//Deck Class
foreach($json->class as $deckclass){
    $userclass = $deckclass->name;
}
```

However, `$json->class` doesn't work as `class` is a PHP keyword which can't be used.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Are you sure? when i test the code it actually works.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/416aa5f17af677c96c6a4caabd4dbc49d8d812ae

What is actually the error message here?

Comment: It should work. What error message you get? How is your `$json` constructed?

Comment: Argh. It does work. My code editor was flagging it as an error but it was actually executing correctly. My apologies.